# WPF Webrowser in C# and XAML load slowly with repeated viewings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to start by saying that I am extraordinarily new to C# and XAML, so this could be a particularly stupid question. However, I haven't had much luck searching.

I have a rather basic WPF program made out of one window and three pages. Basically, one page has a Grid with two buttons: one that says "Bing" and the other that says "Google". This window has `ShowNavigationUI` set to `false`. If the user clicks on the Bing button it directs to `Bing.xaml` using the following code:

```
    private void Bing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BingPage bingPage = new BingPage();
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(bingPage);
    }
```

This loads a Page with a `WebBrowser` set to load bing.com. This Page has `ShowNavigationUI` set to `true`. The "Google" button does the same thing, however it has a `WebBrowser` set to load google.com, with that page also having the `ShowNavigationUI` set to `true`.

Everything works as intended. You can click on Bing, press the back button in the navigation UI, then press the Google button. However, if I do this too much the pages start drastically slowing down with the load and will eventually just show me a white screen.

I'm not sure why this is and how to fix it, so if anyone has an idea I'd love to know.

Comment: I think every time  you click on Bing/Google button creating new BingPage/GooglePage  and added to this.NavigationService . You may use RemoveBackEntry() to remove the old entry's  link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jophyjob that doesn't seem to have worked. After enough clicks I still have the same issue.